# Magento: What event would be best to observe for any update to the cart

Tags: magento

What event(s) would be the most solid to observe if I want to do something anytime someone modifies items in their basket/cart, ie: adding products, removing products, and changing quantities...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the cart events available in Magento 1.9 regarding the cart:

checkout_cart_update_item_complete, 
checkout_cart_product_add_after, 
checkout_cart_update_items_before, 
checkout_cart_update_items_after, 
checkout_cart_save_before, 
checkout_cart_save_after, 
checkout_cart_product_update_after

So I think the best for you is checkout_cart_save_before or checkout_cart_save_after, depending on what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Bonus: Event Cheat Sheet https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/